# laravel conditional join based on optional external keys

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join

I got this db structure:
[image]

ddts contains 3 optional external keys (only one of panel_id, sawn_id or veneer_id can contains an external id and other 2 equals to `null`) .
So one ddt can be exatly just one of this 3 types:

1. sawn
2. panel
3. veneer

I need to extract for every company_id(another external key) i will sum some data from panels,sawns and veneers, but before sum it i need even to convert some of them in kgs too (with a function implemented by me).

In the ddts model ive the methods: panel(),sawn(),veneer();

I need just the final sum, but i guess that for achieve this i need to build up a huge collection and then manipulate it...
Id like to understand what is best to doing by query and what by code.

My first approach was about:

1. select all companies
2. in a foreach loop all ddts for each company
3. in a foreach loop for each ddt associate a type by selecting it
   trough an if condition steatement
4. in a forache loop selection the value to sum
5. convert it to kgs where is necessary
6. sum it;

but it seems so long and im quite shure that the point 2 and 3 should be done by a JOIN but not so clare how!

Comment: I am sorry to bash but first things first :D why do you mix camelCase with snake_case in your table attributes? My eyes hurt.

Comment: @Kyslik lol ok... i will not edit this now...but ill keep it as fair suggestion for the future

Comment: maybe i don't follow something, but can't you just left join everything and sum with an IFNULL to clean it up?

Comment: @GoatHater what u mean by "and sum with an IFNULL to clean it up"

Comment: left joining on optional tables will create nulls, which will break sums.  A IFNULL can be used to eliminate nulls to sum correctly.